# Proofs of Simplicity of $A_n$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, math-history, simple-groups

There are different proofs of simplicity of the group $A_n$, and one can get at least two proofs by choosing randomly 10 books of the subject, so I will not go into *what are these proofs?* Rather, I would consider, *the original references* of these proofs. Can one give links for original proofs among the different proofs, including that of Galois or Abel?

Comment: I think Galois only proved that $A_5$ is simple and that Jordan was the first to prove that $A_n$ is simple for all $n \ge 5$, but I may be wrong!

Comment: May be, you are right. Reading these statements in several books confused me, so simply, I posted it in question.